# Powers of a simple matrix and Catalan numbers

Tags: sequences-and-series, matrices, catalan-numbers, experimental-mathematics, algebraic-combinatorics

Consider $m \times m$ anti-bidiagonal matrix $M$ defined as:

$$M_{ij} = \begin{cases}
      -1, & i+j=m\\
\,\,\  1, & i+j=m+1\\
\,\,\, 0, & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$

Let $S_n$ stand for the sum of all elements of the $n$-th power of the matrix:

$$S_n=\sum_{ij}\left(M^n\right)_{ij}.$$

Prove that for integer $0 < k < m$:

1. $S_{2k}=C_{k-1}$, where $C_k$ is $k$-th Catalan number;
2. $S_{2k+1}=0$,

and, additionally,

3. $S_{2m+1}=(-1)^{m-1}$.

PS: In fact, the first equality holds much longer up to $k=2m$. Besides $S_{4m+2}=C_{2m}-1$.

Comment: Nice exericse, but where is it from and how far have you gotten already?

Comment: I had discovered it "experimentally" playing with the matrices in _Mathematica_ and checked it up to rather high values of $m$ about an hour before I posted this question. Since then little progress was achieved, except for finding (again experimentally) a closed form for the coefficients of the characteristic polynomial of $M$.

Comment: Okay, let's get some work done. Let $J$ be the $m \times m$-matrix whose all entries are $1$. Then, for each $m \times m$-matrix $X$, the sum of all entries of $X$ is $\operatorname{Tr}\left(JX\right)$. Thus, we are interested in the matrices $JM^n$ for various $n$. There seems to be an explicit form for these matrices.

Comment: Let $w$ be the column vector of size $n$ whose all entries are $1$. My conjecture is that each column of $JM^n$ is some ballot number times $w$. It should be easy to prove this by induction on $n$ once the exact formula (which ballot number) is found.

Comment: Okay, here is a general formula based on numerical evidence. For any integers $u$ and $v$, we let $b_{u,v} = \dbinom{u}{v} - \dbinom{u}{v-1}$; this is called a "ballot number". Let $\omega : \left\{1,2,\ldots,m\right\} \to \left\{1,2,\ldots,m\right\}$ be the permutation sending each $i \in \left\{1,2,\ldots,m\right\}$ to $m+1-i$ (that is, the unique order-reversing permutation of this set). Note that $\omega^2 = \operatorname{id}$. Then, I believe that $J S^n e_{\omega^n j} = a_{n,j} w$ for all $n \geq 1$ and $j \in \left\{1,2,\ldots,m\right\}$, where $a_{n,j}$ is ...

Comment: ... defined by $a_{n,j} = \left(-1\right)^{j-1} b_{n-1, \left\lfloor \left(n+1\right)/2\right\rfloor - j}$. This is easy to check for $n = 1$, and should follow by induction over $n$, using the fact that $S e_{\omega i} = e_i - e_{i-1}$ for all $i > 1$ and $S e_{\omega 1} = e_1$.

Comment: The induction step boils down to checking that $a_{n,j} = a_{n-1,j} - a_{n-1, j+\left(-1\right)^n 1}$ for all $n \geq 2$ and $j \in \left\{1,2,\ldots,m\right\}$, where we set $a_{n, k} = 0$ whenever $k \notin \left\{1,2,\ldots,m\right\}$. This cannot be difficult.

Comment: Ah right, my formula holds only for $n \in \left\{1,2,\ldots, 2m\right\}$. (This is required in the induction step, in the case when $n$ is even and $j = m$.) This is somewhat of a pain in the ass for your claim 3, because you want $n = 2m+1$ there. But this shouldn't be too hard to tweak.

Comment: Concerning the equality 1) could it be simpler to consider only the matrix $H=M^2$ stating that the total sum of its $k$-th power up to $k=2m$ is $C_{k-1}$?

Comment: I thought that too, but $H$ isn't as nice as I expected it to be.

Comment: Also, please read $M$ for $S$ in all my comments above (sorry for the typo!).

Comment: @darij grinberg: I think your idea is correct. Could you post it in a complete form as an answer, even if it does not yet cover the claim 3?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have time (semester just starts). Feel free to write it up yourself; it might even make a nice note (just acknowledge me if you publish it).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Acknowledgement

The idea of the proof and especially the closed form (2) are due to [darij grinberg](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/586/darij-grinberg).

#### Preliminaries

Let numbers $b^n_i$, where $n$ and $i$ are integer numbers ($n>0$), be given by recurrence relation:
$$(1)\quad
b^1_i=\delta_{0i}+\delta_{1i},\quad 
b^{n+1}_i=
\begin{cases}
b^n_i-b^n_{i-1},&n \text{ even }\\
b^n_i-b^n_{i+1}, &n \text{ odd }
\end{cases}.
$$

Then the following explicit expression applies:
$$(2)\quad
b^n_i=(-1)^{i}\left[
\binom{n-1}{\left\lfloor\frac{n-1}{2}\right\rfloor-i}-
\binom{n-1}{\left\lfloor\frac{n+1}{2}\right\rfloor-i}
\right].
$$

For $n=1$ the statement is obviously valid. Substituting (2) into right-hand side of (1) separately for odd and even $n$ one ends up with the same expression (2) upon replacement of $n$ with $n+1$.

The following observations are important:
$$
\begin{align}
&(2a)\quad b^n_0=0, \text{ for even } n;\\
&(2b)\quad b^n_1=C_{\frac{n-1}{2}}, \text{ for odd } n;\\
&(2c)\quad b^n_i=0,\text{ for } i>\left\lfloor\frac{n+1}{2}\right\rfloor.
\end{align}$$

#### Proof of the claims

It is convenient to introduce besides matrix $M$ the antidiagonal matrix $\Gamma$:

$$\varGamma=\begin{cases}
1, &i+j=m+1\\
0, &\text{otherwise}
\end{cases},$$

and construct the matrices $L_n=\varGamma^n M\varGamma^{n-1}$ and ${\cal L}_n: \{{\cal L}_1=L_1;\ {\cal L}_n=L_n{\cal L}_{n-1}\}$.

$L_n$ is lower- or upper-bidiagonal matrix for odd and even $n$, respectively. The diagonal elements are $1$ and subdiagonal (or, respectively, superdiagonal) elements are $-1$. Note that due to identity $\varGamma^2=I$ the following equality holds:
$$
{\cal L}_n=\varGamma^n M^n.
$$
Thus the action of ${\cal L}_n$ on a vector is up to permutation of elements equivalent to action of $M^n$.

Consider now the vectors
$u^{n}={\cal L}_n u$, where $u$ is $m$-dimensional "all-ones" vector. Then the following recurrence relation holds for any $i=1\dots m$ and any $n>0$:
$$(3)\quad
u^{1}_i=(L_1u)_i=\delta_{1i},\quad 
u^{n+1}_i=(L_{n+1}u^n)_i=
\begin{cases}
u^n_i-u^n_{i-1},&n \text{ even }\\
u^n_i-u^n_{i+1}, &n \text{ odd }
\end{cases},
$$
with a convention $u^n_0=0$ and $u^n_{m+1}=0$.

Now observe strong resemblance of (3) and (1). The fact that $u^n_0\ne b^n_0$ for odd $n$ does not matter as $u^n_0$ enters the recursion only for even $n$. One concludes that $u^n_i=b^n_i$ for all $i=1\dots m$ as long as $b^{n-1}_{m+1}=0$ for even $n$, which fails firstly for $n=2m+2$.
Thus:
$$
\forall i=1\dots m, \forall n=1\dots (2m+1):\quad u^n_i=b^n_i.
$$

The completion of the proof is easy. In fact:
$$
(4)\quad S_n=uM^nu=u{\cal L}_nu=\sum_{i=1}^m u^{n}_i=\begin{cases}
u^{n-1}_m,& n\text{ odd }\\
u^{n-1}_1,& n\text{ even }
\end{cases}.
$$

For $n\le2m+1$ the equation amounts to:

$$
\text{for odd } n:\quad S_n= 
b^{n-1}_m=\begin{cases}
0, &n<2m+1\\
(-1)^{m+1}, & n=2m+1
\end{cases};
$$
$$
\text{for even } n:\quad S_n=b^{n-1}_{1}=C_{\frac{n}{2}-1}.
$$

Thus all three claims of the question are proved.

#### Concluding remark

One may wonder why the equality $S_{2k}=C_{k-1}$ holds for much higher values of $k$ (up to $2m$). The reason is seen from the equality (4). As the $u^n$-vector starts "corrupting" from the end, it requires additional $2m$ recursion steps till $u^n_1$ starts deviating from $b^n_1$. To be more specific the equality $u^n_i=b^n_i$ holds up to $n=2(2m-i)+1$.